# I should set fsck manually every time my pc boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, permissions, fsck

I just messed up by Ubuntu permissions. I don't know which of commands I used is the problem:( after I see luck sign on all of the folder I have in my home restart my system and then just see grub terminal, I set root and prefix and reboot it and show me grub menu. I select my ubuntu but it show me that fsck should fix manually. I type fsck dev/sda6 and I can see my ubuntu screen. But still I have problem by permissions. What should I do? Is there any way to set permissions as default?

I think all of the problems are related to permissions:/
Thanks for any help...

Comment: The easiest way to restore permissions is to restore files from your backups, (*or create a script that copies the the permissions found on backup files & replaces your real file-systems permissions with those found on backups*), but without clues as to what you did, we cannot really provide much help.  I'd likely boot a *live* system & explore *logs* to remind yourself what you did in the last session before you rebooted; which is when the problems were likely done.

Comment: If you can, boot a live USB stick, mount the main system partition (of the broken OS) to `/mnt`, and do `tail /mnt/home/[your username]/.bash_history` to see what the last few commands you've ran were (and [edit] your question to include those commands)